# How to safely access collection from multiple threads using TPL pipeline

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

Here is very simplified code sample with using TPL Dataflow:

```
//This is collection where I register all items that need to be processed by pipeline
//MyData is simple class with 2 properties = int Id, bool IsCompleted       
private ConcurrentBag<MyData> completedItems = new ConcurrentBag<MyData>();
//This method may be called multiple times in a very short time frame which means that
//few pipelines may be running simultaneously.
public void InitiateProcess(List<MyData> inputData)
{
    inputData.ForEach(ent => completedItems.Add(ent));
    StartPipeline(inputData);
}
public void StartPipeline(List<MyData> inputData)
{
    //Here goes TransformBlock downloadBlock=...
    //Here goes TransfromBlock processBlock=...
    //In the resultBlock I would like to update corresponding item in completedItems bag.
    var resultBlock = new ActionBlock<MyData>(data =>
    {
        var completedItem = completedItems.FirstOrDefault(ent => ent.Id == data.Id);
        if (completedItem != null)
            completedItem.IsCompleted = true;
    });
}
```

My main goal is to register items that have completed successfully. Nothing very complicated, but the more I learn about parallel programing, the more I understand how complicated it can be and one should be very careful using it. I understand there might be multiple different threads trying to access `completedItems` collection at the same time. I have done some research and using `ConcurrentBag` to keep track of these items seems like a good approach. So my question is if there is any underlying danger using this approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentbag-1?view=netcore-3.1#thread-safety)

> All public and protected members of ConcurrentBag are thread-safe and may be used concurrently from multiple threads.

This means that `ConcurrentBag<T>` is designed to be accessed by multiple threads without the concern of them interfering each other

EDIT: I just noticed that you are using `FirstOrDefault` which as again per the docs

> However, members accessed through one of the interfaces the ConcurrentBag implements, including extension methods, are not guaranteed to be thread safe and may need to be synchronized by the caller.

With that said `FirstOrDefault` might not be thread safe, and `ConcurrentBag<T>` allows duplicates to be present. Maybe switching to `ConcurrentDictionary` or using a `List<T>` with a `lock` statement would be better in your case

Comment: Thank you for answer! Yes, you are right. I better switch to `ConcurrentDictionary` and then access and update members with `TryUpdate`!